# R statistics, change ranked tables to paired

Tags: r, reformat

I have data for many tables like:

```
event_id   player   finish
1          a        1
1          b        2
1          c        3
1          d        4
2          b        1
2          e        2
2          f        3
2          a        3
2          g        5
```

Many event_id's, each from 5 to 20 players, finish may be tied.

In order to use the PlayerRatings package in **R** I would like to reformat the tables to be like:

```
event_id   player1   player2 result
1          a         b       1
1          a         c       1
1          a         d       1
1          b         c       1
1          b         d       1
1          c         d       1
2          b         e       1
2          b         f       1
2          b         a       1
2          b         g       1
2          e         f       1
2          e         a       1
2          e         g       1
2          f         a       0.5
2          f         g       1
2          a         g       1
```

An event_id of 4 players will have 4*3/2 = 6 records
in the new table, 5 players will have 5*4/2 = 10 records
and so on.
If player "a" has "finish" less than player "b" the "result"
is 1. If "finish" is equal the "result" is 0.5.
If player "a" has finish greater than player "b" then
the "result" would be 0.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Conditional logistic regression can be done with `survival::coxph` without this complexity.

Comment: Woopsadaisy, my mistake, meant to write: in order to use the R package PlayerRatings which requires the data input I described. At present I develop the data input in MS Access but is slow and tedious for large amount of data circa 1M records. Was hoping for a speedup with an all R solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here a `data.table` solution. I am using it for the grouping and syntax features. The code is a little bit complicated so I give here the idea.

1. group per event_id
2. for each event, create a combinations of player , suing `combn`
3. for each combinations of player computer the *finish* score using a nested `ifelse`

Here the whole code:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[,{ids <- do.call(rbind,combn(seq_along(player),2,simplify=FALSE))
      z <- mapply(function(x,y){
            z <- ifelse(finish[x]>finish[y],0,
                   ifelse(finish[x]<finish[y],1,0.5))
            data.frame(player[x],player[y],z)
            },
            ids[,1],
            ids[,2])
      data.frame(t(z))

     },event_id]

    event_id player.x. player.y.   z
 1:        1         a         b   1
 2:        1         a         c   1
 3:        1         a         d   1
 4:        1         b         c   1
 5:        1         b         d   1
 6:        1         c         d   1
 7:        2         b         e   1
 8:        2         b         f   1
 9:        2         b         a   1
10:        2         b         g   1
11:        2         e         f   1
12:        2         e         a   1
13:        2         e         g   1
14:        2         f         a 0.5
15:        2         f         g   1
16:        2         a         g   1
```

Comment: Thank you agstudy. Your code runs exactly as requested. For small datasets no problem but for 300K records ran too slow. Your explanation of the syntax was apprecited!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a merge solution: The second line is all it's really about.

```
a<-data.frame(event_id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),player=letters[c(1:5,3:8)],finish=c(1,1,3:5,1:6))
b<-merge(a,a,by.x="event_id",by.y="event_id",suffixes = c(".x",".y"))
b$score<-b$finish.x<b$finish.y
b$score[b$finish.x==b$finish.y]<-0.5
c<-b[b$player.x!=b$player.y & as.character(b$player.x)<as.character(b$player.y),c("event_id","player.x","player.y","score")]
```

Comment: Thank you user1965813. A superb solution that handles 300K dataset quite fast. An excellent script, many thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, @cousin_pete. If you are happy with it, would you consider accepting it as the correct answer?